How do I plot a line with a plot that has dates on the x axis and a continuous variable on the y axis
I'm trying to plot the observed vs projected recruitment of a clinical trial. I have a reproducible example below where I can get the observed, but when I try to add the projected recruitment (which is 20 per month) I can't get a line superimposed.
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

# Generate 50 unique patient IDs
patient_ids <- paste0("Patient", 1:50)

# Generate random recruitment dates within a year
recruitment_dates <- sample(seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-12-31"), by = "day"), 50)

# Create a data frame with patient IDs, recruitment dates, and recruitment order
patients <- tibble(
  Patient_ID = patient_ids,
  Recruitment_Date = recruitment_dates
)

# Sort the dataset based on recruitment dates
patients <- patients[order(patients$Recruitment_Date), ]

# Add a column for recruitment order
patients$Recruitment_Order <- 1:nrow(patients)

# Display the dataset
print(patients)

ggplot(patients, aes(x = Recruitment_Date, y = Recruitment_Order)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = 20, intercept = 0, color = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
  labs(x = "Recruitment Date", y = "Recruitment Order") +
  ggtitle("Recruitment Order vs. Recruitment Date")


You need the right units — the unit for Date objects is days. If you want a line with an intercept of 0 at the first date and a slope of 20/month you need something like
sl <- 20*12/365
int <- -sl*as.numeric(min(patients$Recruitment_Date))
gg0 + geom_abline(slope = sl, intercept = int)

where gg0 is the rest of your plot.
